# Prerequisite to study smooth 4-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, 4-manifolds

I am quite interested in understanding smooth 4-manifolds. What are the necessary prerequisites in order to start my study? Also can you please suggest me some good books from where I can start? Thanks in advance.

Edit : I have studied Hatcher upto Cohomology, first 3 chapters of Milnor's Morse Theory, Riemannian Geometry by Petersen (expecting to finish within one month), Complex Geometry from Griffiths and Harris (chapter 0 and have started chapter 1), basic knowledge of connection and curvature on fibre bundles.

Comment: It may be easier to answer your question if you tell us what you already know.

Comment: @Amitai Yuval : I have edited my post

Comment: That seems more than enough to get started. I like Scorpan's *The Wild World of 4-Manifolds* (http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/scorpan.pdf).

Comment: Some other nice book is by Akbulut: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/akbulut/papers/akbulut.lec.pdf